# How do you change background color in the settings of JetBrain's IDE?

Tags: intellij-idea, ide, settings

What are the settings to change the background color in JetBrains' IDE?

- Project explorer pane
- Console pane
- Code editor
- Other Panes

I'm running v12.1.6 Ultimate Version.
Are there major differences between different versions of the software?

Comment: For those looking to change the entire look and feel (the theme) --> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24753893/how-to-set-editor-theme-in-intellij-idea-13-1-3

Answer (score 120, accepted):

#### Console pane:

`Settings / Editor / Colors & Fonts / Console colors`

Console, background

#### Project view:

`Settings / File colors`

Add (Alt+insert), choose 'project files' scope, select a color.

Uncheck the 'Use in editor tabs' checkbox, make sure to check 'Use in project view'

#### Main view (general):

`Settings / Editor / Color & fonts / General`

Text, Default text

Comment: For me this only colors the package not the whole explorer. (I'm on mac, maybe this has something todo with it.)

Comment: I followed the second method (on a Mac), and my selected tab is now noticeably lighter in color than the other tab. Exactly what I was looking for!

Comment: Mihkel L, you need to unselect "Enable File Colors") as well, in order for the current tab to become lighter

Comment: This doesnt really work, it only gives the project-tree a background color, not the whole window.

Answer (score 60):

To change the editor background color in newer versions (after 2017) of Intellij Idea go to ***Settings > Editor > Color Scheme > General*** and then on the right side list expand Text and click on "Default text" then click on the color hex code to get the color wheel.[image: Editor background color change]

Comment: I did this in PHPStorm and it only changed the part of the editor that doesn't have text in it :|

Comment: works for me in idea 2021.2.4

Comment: This is the #1 answer.

Comment: That they still have this option hidden in the text pane ...

Answer (score 47):

For changing the background of the editor goto **File->Settings->Editor->Colors & Fonts->General->Text.** You'll see an item called **"Default text".** On the right you will see a checkbox for **background**. Click on it and choose whatever color you prefer.

Comment: Sadly your answer is at bottom :/

Answer (score 12):

`Editor > Color Scheme > General > Text`
[image]

Answer (score 2):

1. Go to File option top left in the menu bar.
2. Select Settings
3. Select Appearance option in "Appearance & Behavior"
4. Select Intellij option as Theme in UI Options.
5. You should able to see everything in while background much like eclipse.

Comment: works for me on ubuntu thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Beginning with the 2019.1 release, Jetbrain's IDE supports Custom UI Themes, which give full control of the appearance of built-in IntelliJ IDEA UI elements.

[Detailed tutorial about how to create your own custom theme](http://www.jetbrains.org/intellij/sdk/docs/reference_guide/ui_themes/themes_intro.html)

[Blog post about creating custom themes for IntelliJ Platform](https://blog.jetbrains.com/platform/2019/03/creating-custom-themes-for-intellij-platform-ides/)

Answer (score 1):

If you download it from the https://plugins.jetbrains.com, then you will need to install it as the plugin. Go in the settings, install plugin from the disk and select the JAR file from the disk as the screenshot below.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

As of late 2023, it seems that the background colour of panels like Project Files, Structure, Hierarchy and Find are set only in the Theme. Thus the standard approach to this problem is to "write a Theme". If you don't want that hassle, I have found a hack to change the background colour. This allowed me to combine the Eclipse Plus Theme with a lighter background colour in the tool panes.

1. Create a jpg file that is entirely White (or a colour of your choosing)
2. Go to **Settings** > **Appearance** > **Background Image**
3. Select your jpg file
4. Choose an opacity, 100% to use exactly your colour, less to blend the colour in (I use 70% to lighten the default grey)
5. Ensure "Editor and Tools" is set
6. Ensure the multi-tile icon (rightmost of the three) is selected
7. Press OK and enjoy

Note that this should affect every tool pane, unlike other answers here.

[image]

Comment: I don't think so. Ctrl + Alt + S (Settings) -> File Colors

Answer (score -5):

It's very easy: File > Settings > Color Scheme > Set "Classic Light" or other color

Comment: Is not true, you see the words "Classic Light" in the page? My answer is correct

Comment: The problem is not that your answer is incorrect, the problem is that the solution of changing `File > Settings > Color Scheme` has already been mentioned in some other answers, [like this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51246166/2227743), and it's better to not repost existing information.