# How to set editor theme in IntelliJ Idea

Tags: intellij-idea, themes, editor

I'm trying to change the editor color schemes in IntelliJ Idea 13.1.3 community edition to a darker theme. I downloaded a theme from a website [Editor's note: the website has since been replaced with spam, and has been edited out] and imported settings through `File->Import Settings...`. The jar imported successfully and I restarted the IDE, but after restart there is no change in appearance. I have checked in appearance settings and everything is the same as before(no new theme). I'm new to IntelliJ Idea, so I may have missed a step or something. Any ideas?

Answer (score 127, accepted):

OK I found the problem, I was checking in the wrong place which is for the whole IDE's look and feel at `File->Settings->Appearance`

The correct place to change the editor appearance is through `File->Settings->Editor->Colors &Fonts` and then choose the scheme there. The imported settings appear there :)

Note: The [theme site](https://github.com/sdvoynikov/color-themes) seems to have moved.

Answer (score 25):

For IntelliJ in Mac

View -> Quick Switch theme (^`)-> color schema

Comment: This holds good for windows as well currently, go to the File -> Settings --> Editor and rest is same.

Answer (score 15):

It's simple please follow the below step.

1. On IntelliJ press 'Ctrl Alt + S' [ press ctrl alt and S together],
   this will open 'Setting popup'
2. In Search panel 'left top search 'Theme' keyword.
3. In left panel itself you can see 'Appearance', click on this
4. Right side panel you can see Theme: and drop down with following
   option

   - Dracula
   - IntelliJ
   - Windows

just select which ever you want and click on apply and Ok.

I hope this may work for you..[image]

I misunderstood question. Sorry. for editor - File->Settings->Editor->Colors &Fonts and choose your scheme.... :)

Comment: The question was about editor theme and not application theme, I said this in the answer

Comment: Okay, i misunderstood question. Sorry.
for editor - File->Settings->Editor->Colors &Fonts and choose your sheme

Comment: Edit your answer to add this info

Answer (score 4):

If you are using a Windows System. You can press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>S</kbd>, and select Appearance.

Comment: Not only Windows, but Linux too.

Comment: This hides the window on Ubuntu 18.

Answer (score 3):

IntelliJ IDEA seems to have reorganized the configurations panel. Now one should go to Editor -> Color Scheme and click on the gears icon to import the theme they want from external `.jar` files.

Answer (score 2):

For IntelliJ Mac / IOS,

Click on `IntelliJ IDEA` text besides [image] on top left corner then `Preferences->Editor->Color Scheme-> Select the required one`

Answer (score 0):

There is a defined "Quick Switch Scheme..." hotkey combination.
Just press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>`</kbd>, then <kbd>5</kbd> (Theme), and then pick a theme also with number key.

With a little practice, you'll be able to switch between, say,
Intellij Light (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>`</kbd>, <kbd>5</kbd>, <kbd>1</kbd>)

and Dracula (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>`</kbd>, <kbd>5</kbd>, <kbd>2</kbd>)
in a second.