# Intellij : Change variable suggestions background color

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I am new to IntelliJ and trying to change the background color of variable suggestions.I came across "Identifier under caret" which will deal with variable colors but didn't found to change the background color for variable suggestions

[Reference Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zlkUF.png)

Thanks In Advance

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Unfortunately it doesn't seem possible to customise the colours used in autocomplete window - [link to discussion](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/206329749-Change-autocomplete-window-colors). The only way to change the colours is to change the whole theme (e.g switching to Darcula)

Comment: yes as @EamonScullion says the only option is changing the theme reference : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24753893/how-to-set-editor-theme-in-intellij-idea