# How to change color of active tab

Tags: intellij-idea

As the title, I want to change color of active tab to make it to be more different from other. I went through https://devnet.jetbrains.com/thread/274446 but it's not enough!

Is there any way to do that?

Comment: Yes, you need a CSS file

Comment: Could you explain more details? Which file?

Answer (score 5):

I just found out in intellij, it's "file scope" that controls a file's background in project pane as well as in the tabs. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19411510/how-to-change-background-color-for-project-explorer) is the steps to add/modify current scope/tab background.

The default Darcula theme sets the "Tests" scope to this dark green color which is very close to the tab control background. I always lost track of which tab is activated when it's one of the test files. Hope this helps.

Comment: This answer does not answer the question at all. It's about something totally different. Marking is as accepted just confuses people.

Comment: Yea, really as [this says](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19411510/how-do-you-change-background-colors-in-the-settings-of-jetbrains-ide#comment57560685_19449932), this comments is a hack to lighten up the tab to make it distinguishable. Although that is an acceptable solution for many, the true goal of the question was how to edit the tab color freely!!

Answer (score 4):

For IntelliJ IDEA 2021.3.2 (Community Edition)
You can change it in settings:

Settings | Editor | Color Scheme | General | Editor | Tabs | Selected Tab

There you can change `Background` and customize the view in other ways.
[image]

Comment: It looks good! Which intellij version do you use?

Comment: added the idea version info

Comment: Actually I used an old version (intellij 14) . Today I tried with a newer one and your solution works!

Comment: This setting seems (in MacOs 2023.1 at least) to just change the background of that one particular tab.   That sole tab gets the different background whenever it's in focus.   It doesn't follow the "active" tab.   And the "Foreground" setting seems non-functional.   Bug?

Answer (score 3):

The [Active IntelliJ Tab Highlighter](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9562-active-intellij-tab-highlighter) plugin provides a simple way of solving this problem.

1. Go to File -> Settings.
2. In Plugins type "Active IntelliJ Tab Highlighter into the search box.
3. Click on the "Search in repositories" link.
4. Select the Active IntelliJ Tab Highlighter and click on the green Install button.
5. Close the window and restart IntelliJ
6. The active tab should now be highlighted in purple. If required, a different color can be chosen via File -> Settings -> Tools -> Active Tab Highlighter Plugin -> Background (clicking on it brings up a color picker). I personally went with a less garish dark gray color (AAADAA).

Comment: I use Intellij 14 and it seems that the plugin is not available

Comment: Hmmm 14 is quite old now (released May 2016). The plugin says it's compatible with build 145+, which would be version 2016.1 (released August 2016) or higher. Am guessing you're using the Ultimate Edition and would have to pay for an upgrade?

Comment: Yes, im using Ultimate edition. Will retry when I upgrade to new one. Thanks!

Comment: great plugin, It works nicely for me, is improving much more my workflow, I was confusing many times not knowing which tab is the one I'm working on

Answer (score 1):

An alternative way, **Setting > File colors**:

- check Enable File Colors, Use in Editor Tab
- uncheck Use in Project View
- add new scope with your color (ex: Project Files with orange color)

Answer (score 0):

Although the question is quite old, when I googled the problem, this link was in the first three results, so I'll add my 5 cents as well.

Even though I could not find the way to brighten the color of an active tab alone, I was able to solve the problem by changing the color for a given scope altogether. In my case, it was the Tests scope, set to the default green, where the active tab was barely distinguishable from inactive ones, so I went to **Settings > Appearance & Behavior > File Colors** (exact location  may depend on your Idea's version), selected the Tests scope and selected Custom color; the exact RGB value that worked for me was **1A7250**. As a side-effect, the test directory's background color in the Project view also changed, which may or may not be a bad thing.

Regards, hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks. I wish they had the option to change not only the active tab colour but the inactive tab colour too.

Answer (score 0):

I was losing the track of active tab using the darcula theme, in a test directory with a newly created file and staged with git. I ended up changing the File status color.

You will have to make a copy of your theme first:

[image]