# How to set the left margin length of WebStorm Editor?

Tags: webstorm

I spent time looking for answer in Preferences and online and thought of getting help before logging an issue with WebStorm. There is huge left margin in WebStorm and I couldn't find the setting to reduce the length.

[image: See the length from line number to breakpoint]

Another setting I didn't find but not much bothered about it is background color of the Project Explorer. I would like it to black but don't see the setting option.

Comment: I believe for the margin you can just drag and for the background: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19411510/how-to-change-background-color-for-project-explorer

Comment: Have you used "Full screen mode" or "Presentation mode" recently? If you did -- try restarting IDE. Otherwise -- need more info (Does it happens to every file? Maybe some line in this file has lots of icons in that area? IDE version?).

Comment: @Andrew L Thank you for the link to fix the Project View background. Interesting that IntelliJ solution works for WebStorm too. There is no dragging available for left margin though.

Comment: Sorry to hear that, I've always been able to drag the margin.

Comment: @LazyOne, I have 25" monitor, so I never use full screen or presentation mode. And I end up restarting the machine at least twice a day. Yes, it is the case with all JS files and I don't see any icons in that margin (except the breakpoint that I set. I am not aware of and hence haven't configured the WS to show other icons).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Left Margin Length:
There is no way to explicitly change the length. I went into Distraction Free and Presentation Mode and then exited from Presentation and Distraction Free mode (in this order).

Project View Background:
Project view: Settings/File colors, Click +, choose 'project files' scope, select a color. Uncheck the 'Use in editor tabs' checkbox, make sure to check 'Use in project view'