# How to change font color of file tree of RubyMine (Jetbrains IDE)?

Tags: intellij-idea, jetbrains-ide, rubymine

I'm using macOS Catalina and RubyMine 2019.1.

I cannot find how to change font color of file tree of RubyMine (from gray to white).

I could change the background of file tree ([How do you change background color in the settings of JetBrain's IDE?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19411510/how-do-you-change-background-color-in-the-settings-of-jetbrains-ide)), but could not change font color.

Does anyone know how to do it?

[image: Before changing background color]
[image: After changing background color]

Comment: 1) File name colors are part of the GUI Theme that you are using which is AFAIK not user customisable (no options in Settings for that, as it's a part of the GUI Theme). 2) IDE uses different file name colors to display VSC status (https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/project-tool-window.html#file_status_highlight) 3) I think Material UI Theme plugin allows some customisation (not 100% sure as I do not use it myself .. but it has a lot of options/makes quite a bit of changes in the way how IDE looks).

Comment: In case you don't use VCS, you can change the colour for 'Up to date' state (Preferences | Version Control | File Status Colors)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [IntelliJ: How to change background color of Project Folder window?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42846236/intellij-how-to-change-background-color-of-project-folder-window)