# WebStorm, how do you change panels colors? (I am already using Dracula theme)

Tags: intellij-idea, phpstorm, webstorm

I am using Dracula theme but would like to change all the panels to darker color and can't figure how.
See image below, the areas I circled in red
[image]

Comment: Checkout this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19411510/how-do-you-change-background-color-in-the-settings-of-jetbrains-ide/19449932

Comment: By creating a **custom GUI Theme** -- see links in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55312318/783119